# How can I clear a model created with Keras and Tensorflow(as backend)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I have a problem when training a neural net with Keras in Jupyter Notebook. I created a sequential model with several hidden layers. After training the model and saving the results, I want to delete this model and create a new model in the same session, as I have a `for` loop that checks the results for different parameters. But as I understand the errors I get, when changing the parameters, when I loop over, I am just adding layers to the model (even though I initialise it again with `network = Sequential()` inside the loop). So my question is, how can I completely clear the previous model or how can I initialise a completely new model in the same session?

Comment: Usually `tf.reset_default_graph()` should do the trick?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`keras.backend.clear_session()` should clear the previous model. From https://keras.io/backend/:

> Destroys the current TF graph and creates a new one.
>   Useful to avoid clutter from old models / layers.

Comment: What if I only want to delete the parts of the graph associated with a specific model? `keras.backend.clear_session()` sort of feels like a nuclear option

Comment: "[T]here is no way to remove a specific stale model. This is not a bug of Keras but a limitation of the backends." https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5345

Comment: @Zach, perhaps you could run `model_i_want.save('model_dest.h5')`, `keras.backend.clear_session()` then load your model `model_i_want = tf.keras.load_model('model_dest.h5')` ?

Comment: works for pytorch backend as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit old thread, but I was looking for something to clear the session. For **TensorFlow 2.8** I think you need to use `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()`